# Limit user search results in a certain Backoffice perspective

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I'm working with SAP Hybris Backoffice and we have three distinct management Backoffice roles each with its own perspective.

- Product manager
- CMS manager
- User manager

The names of these roles should be clear enough in explaining what they do. Now a manager in Backoffice can be assigned multiple roles because many times in the smaller markets the people who manage users also manage products and articles. Lets say we now want to limit the search results in for example the user view in Backoffice when you are in the Product management perspective only.

The first thing you might think of are the search restrictions that can be added and assigned to a role which adds SQL to the original search query at the end of it to limit results.

This however does not care about what perspective you are in when working in Backoffice. If I for example want to only have this search restriction apply when the user is in the product management perspective it is not obvious how to do so. I think because the scope of a search restriction is global without such granularity.

Then in Backoffice we have the search initializer widget Zk components. These can add search conditions that will be sent to the search engine in Backoffice. However these will affect the user UI in Backoffice because it doesn't sit like just an invisible layer adding at the end of the search the user makes. This adds a problem because the user controls the global and only operator in the Backoffice search interface. So if I add the search initalizer with a condition which needs to add an AND condition at the end of the query to restrict the results and the user then changes the global condition operator to OR then the results the user gets is unpredictable and mostly wrong.

So, have I been missing some middle layer where I can add such a restriction in Backoffice that affects the search made by a user with a certain role in a certain perspective without affecting the Backoffice UI and the user experience?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find this to be a common use case with other developers on the internal SAP network so I had to find myself a solution.

There is the ability to set session search restrictions using the SearchRestrictionService. These will only affect the current session you are using. You can override the widget controller for the perspective chooser or the role switcher. Since changing roles usually changes perspectives this works also.

Then you just add your session local search restrictions for that employee using Backoffice and make their interaction completely personal while still controlling their view and abilities fully with the session search restrictions.